# Aws , Amazon document DB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, amazon-web-services, cloud

i am trying to connect the amazon doucment db to my mongodb shell , but its not working ,
i successfully install the mongoshell on ec2 instacne , amazon doucment db is working on ec2 instance , but not working on my local mongo compass

This is how i created the cluster
[this is the setting of my secuity group cluster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Feptj.png)
Any one know how to connect ?
Here is my code
[Here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZRm2.png)

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Answer (score -1):

#### Connecting Amazon DocumentDB to MongoDB Shell and Compass

To connect to Amazon DocumentDB from your MongoDB shell or MongoDB Compass, you need to ensure that you have the correct connection string and that your network configurations allow for the connection. Here's a step-by-step guide to help you connect:

1. Get the Connection String:

   - Go to the Amazon DocumentDB console.
   - Click on your cluster.
   - In the **Cluster details** tab, click on the **Connect** button.
   - Select the **Connect using MongoDB Compass** option.
   - Copy the provided connection string.
2. Verify Security Group Settings:

   - Ensure that the security group associated with your EC2 instance allows incoming connections on the DocumentDB port (default is 27017).
   - Open the Amazon EC2 console.
   - Select the EC2 instance you're using.
   - In the **Description** tab, look for the **Security groups** section and click on the linked security group.
   - In the security group settings, verify that there is an inbound rule allowing traffic on port 27017.
3. Connect from MongoDB Shell:

   - Open your MongoDB shell on your EC2 instance.
   - Paste the connection string you copied earlier and press Enter.
   - The shell should attempt to connect to your Amazon DocumentDB cluster.
4. Connect from MongoDB Compass:

   - Open MongoDB Compass on your local machine.
   - Click on the **New Connection** button.
   - In the **Hostname** field, paste the connection string you copied earlier.
   - Adjust any other required settings (e.g., SSL).
   - Click **Connect** to attempt the connection.

If you're still experiencing issues, make sure to check the following:

- Ensure that your EC2 instance has internet access and can reach the DocumentDB cluster.
- Double-check that the security group settings allow incoming connections on port 27017.
- Verify that the connection string is copied correctly, including any required credentials or authentication mechanisms.

If you continue to encounter problems, please provide any specific error messages or details you're receiving so that I can assist you further.